# Read String request parameter in Javascript and JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I use the below line of code to get the request parameter value

```
var acctid= <%= request.getParameter("acctid") %>;
```

If the value is **ABCD456** I'm seeing the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: ABCD456 is not defined` and if the values in just a number **345678** it doesn't show any error.

```
var acctid= ABCD456; -> Shows error
var acctid= 345678; -> No error
```

Comment: Hi put that value under quotes i.e : `var acctid= "<%= request.getParameter("acctid") %>";`

Comment: Because you have to wrap ABCD456 with quotes `var acctid = '<% = request.getParameter("acctid") %>';` Otherwise it's looking for a variable that doesn't exist. Numbers will work fine because its a primitive type.